# `executeUpdate()` Hangs continuously because of lock. How to Avoid a table to be getting locked?

Tags: oracle, hibernate

My `executeUpdate()` Update is getting hanged infinitely when I do debugging found out that my table is getting locked after inserting a record that's the reason It is getting stuck.

Therefore My Question Here is what are the possible reasons for a table to be getting locked? or How to avoid a deadlock to be occur while executing insert or update query?

I am using oracle.

Comment: Maybe you start a transaction without committing it?

Comment: check which all query is running on that table? May be multiple exclusive locks on that table or there might be improper queries which might be taking exclusive locks and doing table scan

Comment: @LorenzMeyer, Thanks but I am Using Hibernate so I think It internally calls autocommit.